What's the name of this cable?
I need to know the name of this cable to replace it. I can't get its name. It is 1cm wide.
I found LEMO or XLR but it does not look the same.


Update 1: I found some other cable. I t might be FGG male plug but my cable is 1 cm wide. Not 9mm. (I updated the picture above)

The cable is meant to plug the big panel:




Consider asking on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ and tag as identification and connector. Also, is the same connector used on both ends of the cable and do you know which pins are are supposed to be connected in the cable?

Whats the cable used in?  IT looks like a proprietary one to me.

@RohitGupta Thanks. I updated the question. The cable is meant to plug the big panel https://static.wixstatic.com/media/589cfd_0c5ccafdbdfe43aeac0c32985fab83d2~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_500,h_742,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/Milta_plus.jpg

For anyone interested, this has been asked on the Electrical Engineering stack in Cable replacement - Identification and name of this cable
